# How to call all image in array?

Tags: python, opencv

Using array or list, how I can call both images on the list? What code I should add?

```
import cv2
a = cv2.imread("D:\\a.jpg")
b = cv2.imread("D:\\b.jpg")
arr = []
arr.append(a)
arr.append(b)

cv2.imshow("test", arr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I get the error by running this code.

```
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'
```

Comment: Could you add in question, why the code is not working? and your expected output? any errors you're getting?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you have to show every image in separated window - `cv2.imshow("window 1", a)` `cv2.imshow("window 2", b)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to show every image in separated window

```
cv2.imshow("window 1", a) 
cv2.imshow("window 2", b)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

If you have list with images then you can use `for`-loop

```
for number, image in enumerate(arr, 1):
    cv2.imshow("window " + str(number), image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to show two images in one window, you can do it by using Numpy:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

a = cv2.imread("D:\\a.jpg")
b = cv2.imread("D:\\b.jpg")

v_stack = np.vstack((a, b))
h_stack = np.hstack((a, b))

cv2.imshow('Vertical', v_stack)
cv2.imshow('Horizontal', h_stack)
cv2.waitKey()
```